# Which api is used by Autosar when routting messages using the Can rx/tx interrupt method?

Tags: interrupt, can-bus, autosar

I am a software developer using Autosar standard. I have a question message routing of  two PDUs. My using system use a Can rx/tx interrupt method. I guess called ISR upon receiving can message. And I thought copy rx message to buffer. But I can’t find API providing from autosar standard. I'm curious about the api that is called when routing messages when using the can rx/tx interrupt method. I'm thinking that api based on Autosar criteria will be fixed. Please advise from experts.

Answer (score 0):

PDU level routing is done in the `PduR`, while
Signal-based routing is done in `Com`.

So, on reception, no matter if Polling or Interrupt, `Can` will call `CanIf_RxIndication` with the RxPduId mapped to the PDU. `CanIf` will call `PduR_RxIndication` then, which will lookup the PduRRoutingRelations. It will then call `CanIf_Transmit` with the DestTxPduId and the data of the received PDU.

For Signal-based routing, this is done a level higher in AUTOSAR `Com`.

This does not have to be programmed manually, it is part of an standard AUTOSAR stack.

The routing relations can also already be defined by the SystemDescription/EcuExtract used by the configuration tool, to configure the stack automatically.